# Testing for null JSON Objects in Java/Android

Tags: java, android, json, null

I am getting this LogCat:

```
06-22 15:30:53.731: E/AndroidRuntime(2389): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: "null"
06-22 15:30:53.731: E/AndroidRuntime(2389):     at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
06-22 15:30:53.731: E/AndroidRuntime(2389):     at java.lang.StringToReal.parseFloat(StringToReal.java:310)
06-22 15:30:53.731: E/AndroidRuntime(2389):     at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:300)
06-22 15:30:53.731: E/AndroidRuntime(2389):     at java.lang.Float.valueOf(Float.java:337)
```

Here is code:

```
try
{
    jObject = new JSONObject(result);
    starAvg = jObject.getString("AverageRating"); 
}
ratingsBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.theRatingBar);
ratingsBar.setRating(Float.valueOf(starAvg));
```

Here is the context:

In PHP, I am averaging total numbers in a column in a MySQL table.  When there are ANY rows, it will send back an average of the data in it and it encodes it, and Java picks it up as a JSON object.  But sometimes, there are cases where a table may have 0 rows, so I get this JSON Object:

```
 {"AverageRating":null}
```

My app then crashes and the `LogCat` is as seen above.

The `String` doesn't seem to care if it picks up a Null JSON Object but the app crashes when I do `Float.valueOf(theString)`.

Another side note, I have tried to test this way:

```
if String is Null, Float = 0 
if String is not null, Float.valueOF(String)
```

But it doesn't ever seem to read the String as null.  Is it actually NOT `null` in this case?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use the following method of `JsonObject` to check if a value against any key is null

```
public boolean isNull(java.lang.String key)
```

This method is used to check Null against any key or if there is no value for the key.

Use below snippet

```java
if (jsonObject.isNull("AverageRating")) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Cannot Convert!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //float set to 0
} else {
    Float.valueOf(jsonObject.getString("AverageRating"));
}
```

Comment: `Vipul.isGenius(Shah) ? +1 : null`

Comment: Upon further evaluation, I am moving this answer to the correct one.

Answer (score 4):

```
String str = jObject.getString("AverageRating");
float number = 0.f;
try
{
    number = Float.parseFloat(str);
}
catch (NumberFormatException e)
{
    number = 0;
}
```

`parseFloat()` will throw an exception if it receives `null`.

Comment: 1. don't use exceptions to process non-exceptional conditions 2. don't catch the base class `Exception`.

Comment: it's a design issue. exceptions are for exceptional conditions ... things you don't expect to happen during normal operation of the code. this is just a guideline, and you are often forced to violate this by poor API design. in this case, the entity generating the JSON should either add a number (not a string, not a null object), or leave the field blank if the field is optional.

Comment: I guess you're right. That sounds reasonable. I'm sorry I didn't thought of that a bit before. It now occurs to me; there could be >0 rows and yet the average could be 0. null as a return value clearly is an exception and should be handled appropriatelly.

Comment: @JeffreyBlattman, this is just a religious objection.  There is no universal definition of what constitutes *exceptional*.  Furthermore, the poster did not give us the information to determine whether having 0 rows is an *exceptional* condition or not.  He/she merely acknowledged that it's a case that must be handled.  Depending on the actual application, the performance cost of catching an exception may very well be negligible.  Propagating general rules about not using exceptions is throwing the baby out with the bathwater.  Exceptions can be a very useful language feature.

Comment: @Nate yes, that's why i said in the answer that i wrote that this only applies if receiving a null value is exceptional. i wouldn't call it religious, i'd call it purist.

Comment: @JeffreyBlattman, I totally agree that checking against null is a good/better solution. What I would disagree with is absolutist statements, which you made in your comment above, and in your answer ("... in the field at **all** times."). If the row will be empty 1 in 1000 times, that's not **all** the time, and it's not unexpected. But, it still may be checked infrequent enough that performance costs of exception handling may be negligible/tolerable. I can guarantee people will read your comment above and take it as a general statement, and as such, I think it's poor advice.

Comment: ... and although purist is a fine description, I used the word *religious* because when you introduce a subjective concept like *exceptional*, you are creating a rule that can't be proven or disproven (like *my God* vs. *your God*). Preferring to reserve exception handling for less frequent error handling is fine ... making absolutist statements is *almost* never (!) good.

Comment: the definition of exceptional in the Java language is not subjective. don't take my word for it ... "Exception are such anomalous conditions (or typically an event) which changes the normal flow of execution of a program. Exceptions are used for signaling erroneous (exceptional) conditions which occur during the run time processing.". in a nutshell, exceptional means unexpected. that being said, that use of exceptions in many APIs does not conform to that definition so i understand where folks get confused.

Answer (score 0):

check for null before you parse the value,

```
String s = jObject.getString("AverageRating");
if (s != null) {
  double rating = Double.parseDouble(s);
  // whatever
}
```

that being said, if the value of `AverageRating` is really a number, then the entity that is generating the JSON shouldn't add it to the JSON as a string. if there's no value for the field, the field should be absent. if there's a value for the field, it should be a number.

if that were true, you could handle it like this,

```
if (jObject.has("AverageRating")) {
  double rating = jObject.getDouble("AverageRating");
  // whatever
}
```

other posts have suggested simply catching `NumberFormatException`. this is only correct if you expect to have a valid double value in the field at all times and consider it exceptional otherwise. if you know / expect that the field will some times be absent, it does not qualify as an exceptional condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (json != null && json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null){
    // PARSE RESULT 
}else{
    // SHOW NOTIFICIATION: URL/SERVER NOT REACHABLE
}
```

that being said check null value like key as json value.